# SwiftUI - How to add foreground linear gradient on image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am unable to find any related documentation on how to do a linear gradient on the **foreground** for an image I have with SwiftUI.

I have tried to do it like so:

```swift
Image("IconLoseWeight")
  .frame(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
  .padding(.leading, 17)
  .foregroundColor(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
```

Actually, the code shown above doesn't display any errors, but it breaks the code with warnings that make no sense in the top level Stacks (which I think is a bug with Xcode or SwiftUI). If I remove the `foreground` modifier, the code runs perfectly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The task here is to display gradient over an image. To display one view over another SwiftUI provides `ZStack` view, so, the code can have the next structure:

```swift
ZStack {
    <Image>
    <Rectangle with gradient>
}
```

Additionally, to make sure the image we use is resized correctly to the specified frame `resizable` modifier should be applied with correct `contentMode`:

```swift
Image("IconLoseWeight")
    .resizable()                     // Make it resizable
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)  // Specifying the resizing mode so that image scaled correctly
```

After all, we need to apply `frame` and padding parameter to `ZStack` so that gradient has the same size as the image.

The result would look like that:

```swift
ZStack {
    Image("IconLoseWeight")
        .resizable()                    // Making the image resizable to the container size
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) // Setting up resizing mode so that the image scaled correctly

    Rectangle()                         // Shapes are resizable by default
        .foregroundColor(.clear)        // Making rectangle transparent
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom), cornerRadius: 0)   
                                        // Specifying gradient (note that one color is .clear)
}
.frame(width: 30, height: 30)           // Applying frame
.padding(.leading, 17)                  // Applying padding
```

Note, that we use a gradient from `.clear` to `.black` as we need a transparent gradient to make the image visible.

Comment: Is it possible to start the gradient at 100px from the top? So you would have a 100px solid colour then the gradient fades out from there?

Comment: op wanted a gradient on the foreground (Color) not the background (View)

Comment: Do we really need Rectangle() ? We can simple have Image followed by LinearGradient.

Answer (score 67):

That's because foregroundColor wants a `Color`, but `LinearGradient` is a `struct` that conforms to the protocols `ShapeStyle` and `View`.

If I understand you correctly you want to fill the intransparent area of an image with a gradient?

```
ZStack {
  Color.white // For the background. If you don't need a background, you don't need the ZStack.
  LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    .mask(Image("AssetWithTransparency")
      .resizable()
      .padding()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit))
  }.cornerRadius(15)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Great solution and example!

Comment: This piece of code saved my life! Thank you so much, mate!!

Answer (score 9):

The best way to do this as of the most recent SwiftUI release would be to use the `.foregroundStyle()` view modifier. I'm not sure when this approach became available but this code was tested with Xcode 14 and iOS 16.

Sample code below:

```
let gradient = Gradient(colors: [.purple, .cyan, .orange])

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "figure.strengthtraining.traditional")
        .font(.title)
        .foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(gradient, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @RyuX51's answer and it's working well. But some how size and alignment of my image got changed. Because `LinearGradient`'s `frame` isn't set. 
 So here i came up with the solution for just applying gradient to the `Image`,

```
VStack{
    Spacer()
    Button(action: {
        print("Add Photos")
    }, label: {

        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .mask(Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        ).frame(width: 70, height: 70, alignment: .center)
    })
}
```

Comment: `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` is not necessary , but it's fine. Work perfectly !

Answer (score 3):

RyuX51's answer worked for me except the view ended up stretching to fill the available space. I wanted it to shrink to fit the size of the image I was using.

This worked well for my needs:

```
extension View {
    /// Fills in self with `fill`, maintaining self's natural size
    /// - Parameter fill: View to fill in self with (i.e., a gradient)
    /// - Returns: Filled-in version of self
    @ViewBuilder func filled(with fill: () -> some View) -> some View {
        self.overlay {
            fill().mask { self }
        }
    }
}
```

So for example:

```
Image(systemName: "car.2.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 75))
                .imageScale(.large)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .filled {
                    LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                }
                .border(.orange, width: 2)
```

will give you:

[image]